# Можно ли как-то получить ключевое слово от поисковой системы?

Tags: seo

Если на сайт перешли из поисковой системы, то можно ли как-то получить это ключевое слово, по которому нашли и перешли на сайт ?

Comment: Использовать готовые сервисы статистики (гугл аналитика и т.д) В них всё детально показано, кто что набрал и куда перешёл (касательно ресурса к которому она подключена)

Comment: это понятно. Вопрос относится к тому, как сразу при переходе получить ключ, а не при изучении общей статистики .